# spring mvc - HTML form passing request parameter

Tags: java, html, forms, spring-mvc

I started to learn Spring MVC and web development.
I have this method in my Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/deleteCar")
public String deleteCar(@RequestParam("carId") int carid) {
    carService.deleteCar(carid);
    return "redirect:/car/cars";
}
```

How can I pass the request parameter through html form ?

```
<section>
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/car/deleteCar">
    <input type="text" id="deleteCarWithID" value="${carId}">

    </form>
</section>
```

I get this warning:

```
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required int parameter 'carId' is not present]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the name attribute so Mention `name` attribute with the parameter name in input field. Try below code for the same. Also add a submit type button to submit the form.

```
<input type="text" name="carId" id="deleteCarWithID" value="${carId}">
```